# Copy data data from one worksheet to another with a condition

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a macro that helps me to copy data from one worksheet to another in Excel with some conditions. I tried the following code; it works, but I got an infinite loop and I was not able to make the condition correctly in the code (I have to copy only the lines with the drop down list displays (complete), actually it's filled with  3 options (complete/cancel/in process)

```
Sub copier()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, src As Range, dest As Range, i As Integer
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Workload - Charge de travail")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

For i = 2 To ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set src = ws1.Range("A2" & i & ":AG10" & i)
    Set dest = ws2.Range("A2" & i & ":AG10" & i)
    If Source.Cells(1, 4).Value = "complete" Then
         src.Copy Destination:=dest
         dest.Value = dest.Value
         Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you have an extra "End if" in your post... Also, you have your "Next i" inside your if statement.

Comment: the extra end if it has been posted  by mistake , where i can put my condition

Answer (score 0):

Here some changes to your code that might help.

```
Sub copier()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, src As Range, dest As Range, i As Integer

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Workload - Charge de travail")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For i = 2 To ws1.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row   
            ' this is more reliable than the method you used (which relies ont eh workbook being saved)
            ' but there must be no gaps in column A.

        ' Your code would not work.  Think about whay happens as i increases!
        ' ws1.Range("A2" & i & ":AG10" & i)

        Set src  = ws1.Range("A" & i & ":AG" & i+10  )
        Set dest = ws2.Range("A" & i & ":AG" & i+10 )

         If Source.Cells(1, 4).Value = "complete" Then 
             ' what is source?   
             ' What is this trying to do!  I think you mean i+1 not 1.     
             ' I think you mean src not source.  I'm not psychic.

           src.Copy Destination:=dest
           dest.Value = dest.Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: source its for my drop down list

Comment: So the code I wrote only does the copy if yu have selected "complete" in your drop down list.  You need to use a lot more words and give us more info if we are going to be able help you more.

Comment: @Riadh.  Sorry but his isn't a code writing service and I find your explainations hard to follow.  I won't be able to offer you any more help that that already given.  I hope I have helped you somewhat.